# Closed form of an exponential series of $n$-fold convolutions

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, power-series, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $f^{<n>}(x)$ denote the n-fold convolution of $f$ with itself (also called [convolution power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_power)). Is it possible to write the following series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^n}{n!}f^{<n>}(x)$ in closed form?

**Progress so far:**

- So far I've seen several articles in which methods to evaluate $f^{<n>}(x)$ efficiently are presented. However, I am interested in the evaluation of this series and not of $f^{<n>}$ for particular values.

  In the [convolution
  power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_power) wikipedia
  article a **convolutional exponential** of the form

  $$\exp^*(x) = \delta(0) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^n}{n!}f^{<n>}(x)$$

  can be defined, but no closed form is given. I also tried looking around for this so called convolutional exponential, but I was unable to find anything.
- I have the feeling that the closed form of this series is somehow related to the exponential $e^{ix}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^n}{n!}$ but I have not been able to find a solution so far.
- An additional solution is possible by using the Fourier transform ($\mathcal{F}$). By using the Fourier transform, one can arrive to a solution to the series of the form $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{i\mathcal{F}f})$ by using the exponential series property. However, I would like to avoid going to the Fourier domain and back.

Thank you all in advance! :)

Comment: Why the $i^n$ factor ?

Comment: I was thinking that it could be used to use transformations of the form $e^{ix}=\cos (x) + i \sin(x)$. But it is not necessary.